# How to check if a variable exists with a value without "undefined local variable or method"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, undefined, exists

This is a common pattern: If a variable doesn't exist I get an `undefined local variable or method` error.

The existing code has `if variable_name.present?` but this didn't account for the variable not existing.

How can I check the value of the variable and also account for it not existing at all?

I've tried:

```
if (defined? mmm) then
  if mmm.present? then
    puts "true"
  end
end
```

but Ruby still checks that inner `mmm.present?` and throws "no such variable" when it doesn't exist.

I'm sure there's a common pattern/solution to this.

Comment: Does anybody know if there's a similar function like `.presence`, which checks if a variable is `nil` and if it is not, it will output the value. Except in this case it checks for if a variable is `defined?`?

Comment: seems that this is no longer true!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Change the `present?` to `!= ''` and use the && operator which only tries to evaluate the seond expression if the first one is true:

```
if defined?(mmm) && (mmm != '') then puts "yes" end
```

But actually as of 2019 this is no longer needed as both the below work

```
irb(main):001:0> if (defined? mm) then
irb(main):002:1* if mm.present? then
irb(main):003:2* p true
irb(main):004:2> end
irb(main):005:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):006:0> if (defined? mm) then
irb(main):007:1* p mm
irb(main):008:1> end
=> nil
```

Comment: Also pay attention to operators preferences and use parenthesis appropriately, in this case the second part of the expression includes parenthesis, but if you are checking a _boolean_ and you don't use parenthesis for the `defined?(mmm)` the condition would return `true`. So when within a complex comparison it is a good practice to use `(defined?(mmm))`

Answer (score 4):

On Ruby on Rails

```rb
if defined?(mm) && mm.present?
  puts "acceptable variable"
end
```

On IRB

```rb
if defined?(mm) && !mm.blank? && !mm.nil?
  puts "acceptable variable"
end
```

It can make sure you won't get undefined variable or nil or empty value.

**Understand how `defined?` works**

```rb
a = 1
defined?(a) # => "local-variable"

b = nil
defined?(b) # => "local-variable"

c = ""
defined?(c) # => "local-variable"

d = []
defined?(d) # => "local-variable"

$e = 'text'
defined?($e) # => "global-variable"

defined?(f) # => nil
defined?($g) # => nil
```

Note that `defined?` checks variable in the scope it is.

**Why you need `defined?`**

When there is possible of undefined variable presence, you cannot just check it with only `.nil?` for eaxample, you will have a chance to get NameError.

```rb
a = nil
a.nil? # => true
b.nil? # => NameError: undefined local variable or method `b'
```

Comment: Not being fluent in Ruby, but 3 years after an accepted answer could you offer some info on how it relates to the existing answer(s)? Here I suggest explaingin a bit the `.nil?`addition which might be the magic sparing the `then`and taking into account the non existance. But you will for sure know better. Thanks.